# Salesforce Workflow rule works fine on sandbox but not on production

Tags: salesforce, workflow, rules

I have a simple workflow rule that creates a task when a formula evaluates to true. 
Here is the information about the workflow:

**Rule Name**- Account: First EBR Task
**Object**- Account
**Active**: Checked 
**Evaluation Criteria**: Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria
**Description**: Create a new task with subject EBR 45 days after the renewal date
**Rule Criteria**: *IF(Today() - Renewal_Date__c =45,true, false)*

The problem is that it works fine on sandbox, but the same workflow rule would not work on production. 
What may be the problem? Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Debug log would tell you what's going on. Did the workflow fire, what the various fields evaluated to.

Do you really create new account with renewal date set to 45 days ago? Even if you do - can you rely on somebody creating/editing account on exactly 45 days mark? It sounds like time-based workflows might be better for what you're trying to do. Make a time-based action that runs 45 days before renewal date. You might not see effects immediately (it'll start getting queued as you edit accounts) but that's kind of the point - you should be able to see actions in Setup -> Time-based Workflow

Comment: Hi, 
Thank you for your comment!

I tried to read the debug log but there were no messages for my workflow. However, I tested it again and it seems to work fine. It is weird!